# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1'); looping through arrays

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am attaching the URL to the issue I am talking about. If inspected, you can see the error.

I have program that is taking in data in a form and comparing it against json data and then outputting json data. I used an xmlhttprequest to grab the json and convert it to javascript array. I keep getting an error specifically about the following line of code. I will past the entire js file underneath.

Now the code is actually working at this time, but earlier it was not, and obviously I should find and fix the errors no matter what. I have been researching for hours, and can't fix the problem. Help would be so appreciated.

URL: https://oacaa.org/self-sufficiency-calculator/

```js
if (arrBirds[i][1] === userAdultInt && arrBirds[i][2] === userInfantInt && arrBirds[i][3] === userPreschoolInt && arrBirds[i][4] === userSchoolageInt && arrBirds[i][5] === userTeenageInt && arrBirds[i][9] === userCounty)
```

```js
function overIt() {
          
    // Create XMLHttpRequest object.
    var oXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Initiate request.
    oXHR.onreadystatechange = reportStatus;
    oXHR.open("GET","/oacaa.json", true);  // get json file.
    oXHR.send();


    function reportStatus() {
        if (oXHR.readyState == 4) {     // Check if request is complete.

            // Create an HTML table using response from server.
            createTableFromJSON(this.responseText);
        }
    }


    // Create an HTML table using the JSON data.
    function createTableFromJSON(jsonData) {

        const userAdult = document.getElementById("adult").value;
        const userAdultInt = parseInt(userAdult,10);
        const userInfant = document.getElementById("infant").value;
        const userInfantInt = parseInt(userInfant,10);
        const userPreschool = document.getElementById("preschool").value;
        const userPreschoolInt = parseInt(userPreschool,10);
        const userSchoolage = document.getElementById("schoolage").value;
        const userSchoolageInt = parseInt(userSchoolage,10);
        const userTeenage = document.getElementById("teenage").value;
        const userTeenageInt = parseInt(userTeenage,10);
        const userCounty = document.getElementById("county").value;
            
                const userChildren = Number(userInfantInt) + Number(userPreschoolInt) + Number(userSchoolageInt) + Number(userTeenageInt);

       
        var arrBirds = [];
        arrBirds = JSON.parse(jsonData);    // Convert JSON to array.

        for (i = 0; i < 63274; i++){

            if (arrBirds[i][1] === userAdultInt && arrBirds[i][2] === userInfantInt && arrBirds[i][3] === userPreschoolInt && arrBirds[i][4] === userSchoolageInt && arrBirds[i][5] === userTeenageInt && arrBirds[i][9] === userCounty)  {
        
        // EXPENSES
        document.getElementById("housing").innerHTML = arrBirds[i][10];
        document.getElementById("childcare").innerHTML = arrBirds[i][11];
        document.getElementById("food").innerHTML = arrBirds[i][12];
        document.getElementById("transportation").innerHTML = arrBirds[i][13];
        document.getElementById("healthcare").innerHTML = arrBirds[i][14];
        document.getElementById("misc").innerHTML = arrBirds[i][15];
        document.getElementById("taxes").innerHTML = arrBirds[i][16];

        // TAX CREDITS
        document.getElementById("EITC").innerHTML = arrBirds[i][17];
        document.getElementById("CCTC").innerHTML = arrBirds[i][18];
        document.getElementById("CTC").innerHTML = arrBirds[i][19];

        // SELF SUFFICIENCY WAGE
        document.getElementById("hourly").innerHTML = arrBirds[i][20];
        document.getElementById("monthly").innerHTML = arrBirds[i][21];
        document.getElementById("annual").innerHTML = arrBirds[i][22];
        document.getElementById("emergency").innerHTML = arrBirds[i][23];

        const userName = document.getElementById("name").value;
        const userCounty = document.getElementById("county").value;
        //PERSONAL INFO
        document.getElementById("personal-info").innerHTML = "Self Sufficiency Report for" + " " + userName + "'s" + " " + "household living in " + " " + userCounty + "." + " " + "The residents in this household include" + " " + userAdultInt + " " + "adult(s)" + " " + "and" + " " + userChildren + " " + "child(ren)" + ".";

        var x = document.getElementById("form-user-input");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
          x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          x.style.display = "none";
        }

        var j = document.getElementById("income-form");
        if (j.style.display === "block") {
          j.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          j.style.display = "block";
        }

        } else {
          document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "We do not currently have information for this family type. We apologize in advance." }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the length of `arrBirds`? Your loop appears to have a hardcoded end index `for (i = 0; i < 63274; i++){`. Are you sure it's that long?

Comment: I just checked and saw arrBIrds had length 63272 so it crashed on i=63272.  Why not code i<arrBirds.length - always safer like that.

Comment: True... I am going to try this and see if it improves. Thank you both for your comments!

Comment: That completely fixed the problem.... Wow, THANK YOU! I am not proficient enough yet in js to problem solve my own code, so I really appreciate your knowledge. ha!